# If encadeados - como eliminar?

Tags: c#, if

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde tenho o seguinte cenário:

Tenho várias regras (classes de negócios)

onde todas retornam o código do cliente. São classes separadas que vão procurar o código tentativa e erro, se encontrar o código do cliente retorna ele e para por aí.

Como posso utilizar uma regra sem usar um monte de IFs ou IFs encadeados na classe que chama as outras que contém as regras de negócios específicas?

Para as classes específicas, eu usei o design pattern strategy.

EX: Classe Principal

```
 public abstract class Geral
{
    public abstract string retornaCodigo(Arquivo cliente)
    {
        var codigo = "";   // logica  

        return codigo;
    }

}

//Classe derivada 1


public class derivada1 : Geral
{
    public override string retornaCodigo(Arquivo cliente)
    {

        var codigo = "";  // logica  

        return codigo;
    }

}

//Classe derivada 2



public class derivada2 : Geral
{
    public override string retornaCodigo(Arquivo cliente)
    {

        var codigo = "";    // logica 2 

        return codigo;
    }

}

//Classe derivada 3



public class derivada3 : Geral
{
    public override string retornaCodigo(Arquivo cliente)
     {

         var codigo = "";  // logica 3 

       return codigo ;
     }

}


//Classe de Negocio 



public class Negocio
{

    public string Codigo()
    {
        var arquivo = new Arquivo();
        var derivada1 = new derivada1().retornaCodigo(arquivo);

        var derivada2 = new derivada2().retornaCodigo(arquivo);
        var derivada3 = new derivada3().retornaCodigo(arquivo);


        if (derivada1.Equals(null))
        {
            return derivada1;
        }
        if (derivada2.Equals(null))
        {
            return derivada2;
        }

        if (derivada3.Equals(null))
        {
            return derivada3;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

o que eu queria e que não tivesse que usar Ifs na classe de Negocio para a validação se achou ou não o código onde o mesmo pode cair em qualquer condição deu exemplo de 3 classes mais tenho mais de 15 condições ,e pode aumentar ,ai no caso seria muitos Ifs.

Comment: poderia exibir seu codigo ?

Comment: coloquei o exemplo de código

Comment: O código apresentado não faz muito sentido e possui muitos erros, tem como você apresentar um exemplo mais concreto e explicar melhor o seu objetivo?

Comment: era só um exemplo ,mais mesmo assim arrumei o código

Answer (score 1):

Não percebi muito bem o objetivo do método `Codigo` da classe `Negocio`, mas imagino que o que pretenda devolver um primeiro valor que não seja nulo ou vazio.

Se assim for, o seguinte código pode ajudá-lo a minimizar os `IF`:

```
public class Negocio
{
    public string Codigo()
    {
        var arquivo = new Arquivo();

        string derivada1 = new derivada1()?.retornaCodigo(arquivo);
        string derivada2 = new derivada2()?.retornaCodigo(arquivo);
        string derivada3 = new derivada3()?.retornaCodigo(arquivo);

        return RetornaValor(derivada1, derivada2, derivada3);
    }

    private string RetornaValor(params string[] strValores)
    {
        foreach (var strValor in strValores)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValor))
                return strValor;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Só precisa é de passar todas as variáveis `derivada` por parâmetro para o método `RetornaValor`.

Outra forma seria passar uma lista de `string`:

```
private string RetornaValor(List<string> strValores)
{
    foreach (var strValor in strValores)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValor))
            return strValor;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Mas aí precisaria juntar todas as variáveis na lista.

---

Visto que o seu código não ficou muito claro, pode ter que fazer uns *tweaks* para chegar onde pretende.